# How to create peering between an Azure VNET and Azure K8s POD?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, vpn, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

We have a requirement to connect a K8s POD to an Azure VPN Gateway in a secure manner. This is what our network topology is:

[image]

Firstly is this possible to achieve and secondly how would we go about creating this peering? If peering isn't the best option then what would you recommend to solve this problem? TIA

We have created the VPN gateway, VNET, and a local network and confirmed that they can communicate in both directions. The problem is how we bring this into K8s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I have created a virtual network gateway vnet local network gateway like below:

[image]

In virtual network added gateway subnet like below:

[image]

created local network gateway :

[image]

On-premise try to configure  [Routing and remote access role](https://www.mcse.gen.tr/demand-dial-ile-site-to-site-vpn/) in tools -> select custom configuration ->Vpn access, Lan routing ->finish

in network interface select -> New demand-dial interface -> in vpn type select IPEv2 and in the destination address screen provide public IP of virtual network gateway

[image]

Now, try to create a connection like below:

[image]

[image]

Now, I have created an aks cluster with pod like below:

[image]

To communicate with pod make sure to use ***Azure Container Networking Interface (CNI)*** every pod gets an IP address from the subnet and can be accessed directly each pod receives an IP address and can directly communicate with other pods and services.
you can  AKS nodes based on the maximum number of pod can support. Advanced network features and scenarios such as Virtual Nodes or Network Policies (either Azure or Calico) are supported with Azure CNI.

When using Azure CNI, Every pod is assigned a VNET route-able private IP from the subnet. So, ***Gateway should be able reach the pods directly.*** [Refer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/configure-kubenet.md#virtual-network-peering-and-expressroute-connections)

[image]

- You can use AKS's advanced features such as virtual nodes or Azure Network Policy. Use  [Calico network policies](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.9/security/calico-network-policy). network policy allows an traffic between pods within a cluster and communicated

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: backend-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: frontend
```

[image]

To more in detail ***refer*** this link:

[Azure configure-kubenet - GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/configure-kubenet.md)

[Network connectivity and secure in  Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-network)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the comprehensive answer. We will be running through this today.